# How to compare two date fields in same document in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, dsl, elk

In my elastic search index, each document will have two date fields `createdDate` and `modifiedDate`. I'm trying to add a filter in kibana to fetch the documents where the `modifiedDate` is greater than `createdDate`. How to create this filter in kibana?
Tried Using below query instead of greater than it is considering as gte and fetching all records

```
GET index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script" : {
                        "inline" : "doc['modifiedTime'].value.getMillis() > doc['createdTime'].value.getMillis()",
                        "lang"   : "painless"
                        }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Which version are you running?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few options.

**Option A:** The easiest and most performant one is to store the difference of the two fields inside a new field of your document, e.g.

```
{
   "createDate": "2022-01-11T12:34:56Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2022-01-11T12:34:56Z",
   "diffMillis": 0
}
{
   "createDate": "2022-01-11T12:34:56Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2022-01-11T12:35:58",
   "diffMillis": 62000
}
```

Then, in Kibana you can query on `diffMillis > 0` and figure out all documents that have been modified after their creation.

**Option B:** You can use a [`script` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html)

```
GET index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": """
            return doc['createdDate'].value.millis < doc['modifiedDate'].value.millis;
          """
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note: depending on the amount of data you have, this option can potentially have disastrous performance, because it needs to be evaluated on ALL of your documents.

**Option C:** If you're using ES 7.11+, you can use [runtime fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/runtime.html) directly from the [Kibana Discover view](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/discover.html#add-field-in-discover).

You can use the following script in order to add a new runtime field (e.g. name it `diffMillis`) to your index pattern:

```
emit(doc['modifiedDate'].value.millis - doc['createdDate'].value.millis)
```

And then you can add the following query into your search bar

```
diffMillis > 0
```

Comment: I'm using version 7.10.2 and I'm trying to use it as dsl for kibana visualization.. the second approach is throwing this error class_cast_exception: Cannot apply [<] operation to types [org.elasticsearch.script.JodaCompatibleZonedDateTime] and [org.elasticsearch.script.JodaCompatibleZonedDateTime]

Comment: I've updated the script in option B, please try again

Comment: the condition is getting picked as greater than equals instead of greater than.. same issue I faced with painless type query. Updated the question. It is giving all records in output

Comment: Can you show a document where you think both dates are equal but are not?

Comment: Actually when I give this in kibana as DSL query it is working fine.. but the api output shows different count and relation.. sry for the confusion. The API is giving same count for all index "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 10000,
      "relation" : "gte"
    }

Comment: If the result is having more than 10000 counts, the hit count is showing as 10000.. otherwise the script is running fine.. thanks

Comment: In order to get the exact number of hits, you need to add `"track_total_hits": true` to your query